# How can I write a regex that allows 2 digit decimals and blanks, but no spaces?

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have the following regex, used in an ASP.NET `RegularExpressionValidator`:

^\d*(.\d[0-9]?)?$

This expression does everything I need, except prevent an input of ONLY spaces. It limits the input to a 0, 1, or 2 digit number, and won't allow spaces inside or after the number. And it allows the field to be blank (nothing entered at all).

I want to prevent the user from typing in just spaces, because I realize that sometimes users will wipe out the values of a field with the space bar instead of the delete key.

However, for some reason it allows just spaces to be entered, almost like it thinks a space (or spaces) is the equivalent of a blank field (null).  What am I missing?

EDIT: added ^ character to beginning of expression, missed it when copying in to this question.

Comment: Seems like the regex does what you want, and the code which uses it allows for blanks regardless of the regex.

Comment: I have considered that it was an issue with .NET's RegularExpressionValidator.  I can remove spaces in the code on the back side, but was hoping to be able to get this to work to prevent the spaces int the first place.  Seems odd that .NET would cause it to behave that way.

Comment: Also, I WANT it to allow a blank field.  I just don't want it to allow space characters.  Two different things.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only from 0 to 3 digits I suggest you to use this one instead

```
^\d*(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

This tells that from the beginning of the string there can be only 0, 1 or 2 digits and no other characters. You miss the check from the beginning of the string I think

EDIT:

I tested your regex here http://regex101.com/r/hC1dL6 and it does not give problems... I think it is possible that the input is trimmed before reaching your regex. I suggest you to perform a test in that way.

**EDIT2**

From [here](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t66339-regular-expression-validation-spaces-problem.html)

> Field validators only fire when there is content in the field being
>   validated. To check that a field has data, and correct date, you need
>   to use two validators. The required field validator will ensure that
>   data is entered, and your second validator (eg. regular expression
>   validator) will ensure that the data entered is in the required
>   format.

the suggestion is to use two validators.

Comment: Sorry, bad job of copy|paste on my part.  I actually had the ^ character in front of the expression.  I don't want to limit the number of characters, except to 2 decimal places at most.

Answer (score 0):

Your new regex:

```
^(|\d+(\.\d{1,2})?)$
```

Explanation:

- `^` sets a starting point anchor. It will invalidate `space`s.
- It validates blank.
- It invalidates malformed numbers like `12.` , `.12`
- To disable "capture group" (for better performance, etc), use: `^(?:|\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?)$`

Comment: I tried both expressions you provided, but it still allows spaces unless they are part of input containing other characters.

Comment: @BeachBum my tests does not return matches for spaces. http://regex101.com/r/eX5bR5 could you post your actual regex-testing code?

Comment: It doesn't return matches for spaces for me either in a regex tester.  For that matter, neither did my original expression.  I guess the issue is that in the ASP.NET page using the RegularExpressionValidator, it does.  So for some reason the behavior of that control is a bit non-standard.